# What does "Inject ComEmuHK" option of ConEmu does exactly?

Tags: conemu

Since when this option enabled "git svn rebase" stays stalled and does nothing, I'm starting to think that it's not totally innocent.
However since it's checked on the default setup, I would like to know what this option does, and why it should be enabled (I guess that it should be since it's the default).

**Q:** What does the "Inject ConEmuHK" does precisely ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is... what ConEmuHk is doing described in [ConEmu docs](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuHk.html#descr).

In brief - it fixes many Win console problems and implements "inprocess" features like ANSI and "-new_console".

Internally - it hooks dozens of WinApi functions.

In theory, it must not break any behavior of running applications, but if it so - you need to report the problem on project issue tracker.

PS. Do you using last ConEmu build?

Comment: This bug has been solved in the last release. Sorry for not looking at the FAQ first.

Comment: Link bitrotted... but, here is a [good alternative](https://conemu.github.io/en/ConEmuHk.html#descr).